# Choosing sheet by name

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code in VB:

```
srcClm2 = Sheet45.Range("B2:B" & lastRowSrc)
```

But I wanna choose sheet by name. I try the different ways, for example:

```
Sheets("Cycle").Range("A2:A" & lastRowSrc)
```

But I have got error: "Type mismatch."

**EDIT:**
This is fragment of my code:

```
Dim srcClm1(), srcClm2()
Dim lastRowSrc As Long

lastRowSrc = Sheets("Line_Cycle_working_sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


srcClm1 = Sheets("Line_Cycle_working_sheet").Range("A2:A" & lastRowSrc)

srcClm2 = Sheets("Line_Cycle_working_sheet").Range("B2:B" & lastRowSrc)
```

Comment: Ok, post the whole code. Or let me confirm, Is this line shown error. I don't think so. Because `Sheets("Cycle").Range("A2:A" & lastRowSrc)` is right.

Comment: Probably wrong name ("Cycle")

Comment: As Nicolas stated, `Sheets("Cycle").Range("A2:A" & lastRowSrc)` is correct as long as 1. your active workbook contains a sheet "Cycle", and 2. lastRowSrc is a number >0. Also, don't forget `Set` in `Set srcClm2 = ...`

Comment: If you want to get an array of  **Values**, your code is O.K.  If you want to define a range, then you need **Set**

Comment: @Robert, rather then posting code in comment, please improve your question.

Comment: @Amit If the name of worksheet would be wrong, another error would be thrown - Subscript out of range.

Comment: @Verzweifler It depends what Robert wants to achieve. If he wants to get reference to range he needs to use `Set` keyword, just like you said. But if he wants to get an array of values from worksheet, he should declare variables as `Variant` and assign the value without using `Set` keyword.

Comment: @mielk - true... that's what happens when people don't read [ask]. other people have to guess what the problem might be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare variables `srcClm1`, `srcClm2` as Variant.

```
Dim srcClm1 As Variant, srcClm2 As Variant
Dim lastRowSrc As Long

lastRowSrc = Sheets("Line_Cycle_working_sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
srcClm1 = Sheets("Line_Cycle_working_sheet").Range("A2:A" & lastRowSrc)
srcClm2 = Sheets("Line_Cycle_working_sheet").Range("B2:B" & lastRowSrc)
```

---

Actually you could skip `As Variant` and declare it just like this:

```
Dim srcClm1, srcClm2
```

since `Variant` type is default. However, it is good practice to add `As Variant` to make it clear that you declare it as `Variant` by purpose and not by mistake.